# Communication between different SignalR hubs?

Tags: c#, signalr, signalr-hub

I'm trying to make a game that uses a similar setup to Jackbox games. It basically means that you have a host client that mobile clients can access by going to https://jackbox.tv and put in a room code + a player name. No downloads required on the phone.

Here is my setup:

- Unity Host Client - Will be used to establish a room. (C#, .NET 2.0 Standard)
- React Native Player Client - Is what players will use to interact with the game. (JavaScript, Expo)
- Server Client - A server that will link games and players together using SignalR as the backend technology. (C#, .NET 5)

The problem I have right now is that I don't quite know how to make my two hubs talk to each other. The two hubs are:

- HostHub - This is where the Unity Clients connect so the server knows what games are available and with what players.
- GameHub - This is where the Player Clients connect and will be assigned to rooms.

I have a Singleton instance of a `ServerManager` on the Server Client which is used to save `Game` and `Player` objects as well as retrieving them (I will add proper persistence management later).

So when I try to use C# events like this in my Host- or GameHub:

```cs
...
ServerManager.Instance.OnPlayerJoinedRoom += ServerManager_OnPlayerJoinedRoom;
...

private void ServerManager_OnPlayerJoinedRoom(object sender, (string, string, string) info)
{
    IClientProxy host = Clients.Client(info.Item1);
    host.SendAsync("PlayerJoined", Extensions.ParamArray(info.Item2, info.Item3));
}
```

I get an error that says `Clients` is Disposed so I can't access it. I found out this is because these are very light objects that have a very short lifespan before they are disposed of, by design.

So what else can I do to make Hubs communicate with each other or is this just not the approach for SignalR?

Comment: This is basically the same as having 2 Controllers talk to each other -> it shouldn't happen and the SDK does not provide a simple way to make it happen. However, it's not at all clear how the hubs are communicating with each other right now, can you expand your sample code?

Comment: Oh okay. Well that explains the problem then. I do understand the controller analogy.

Comment: Basically what I attempted to do was to say that the `ServerManager` class would act as a "bridge" and simply have Events that either Hub could trigger through some method calls. The receiving hub could then just subscribe to those events via the `ServerManager`. But if that isn't possible, then I'll have to redo my structure.

Comment: Looks like you should try using `IHubContext<YourHub>`. This is a way to send messages to clients from outside a hub, https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/signalr/hubcontext?view=aspnetcore-5.0#get-an-instance-of-ihubcontext

Comment: @Brennan So a use-case for me would be; Player joins a game which is picked up via the GameHub. The GameHub now wants to tell the HostHub that a player has joined so the HostHub can send the Host a message to reflect this change. Would that be possible this way?

Comment: You should have only one signal but with multiple hubs. That way HostHub and GameHub can share the same context and collections: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server#multiplehubs

Comment: @GHDevOps Do you want to make this an answer to my question? It would be appreciated so that others can see it too if they run into this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Register multiple endpoints in OWIN startup:

```
app.UseEndpoints(ep => { ep.MapHub<HostHub>("/hostHub"); ep.MapHub<GameHub>("/gameHub"); }
```

Then in your client (ie: JavaScript) just connect with the desired endpoint:

```
var conn = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl('https://localhost:5000/gameHub');
```

All hubs share the same "/signalr" endpoint